# non-JRMP server at remote endpoint

Tags: oracle-nosql

I am trying to figure out how to use Oracle nosql.  I have downloaded and installed version 4.3.11 (with examples).  I have started kvlite both with default params and with the following:
`java -jar lib/kvstore.jar kvlite -port 5000 -root kvroot -host` 
When I run the examples as described at https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26161_02/html/GettingStartedGuide/verifykvlite.html, exceptions are thrown.
Unfortunately, I cannot post the stacktrace as it is on another server that is not accessible from here.

Some of the errors are:
Could not contact any RepNode at: [localhost:5000]
non-JRMP server at remote endpoint

Any assistance would be appreciated.
-Raymond

Comment: I also stopped kvlite, deleted kvroot, and restarted.  This created a new kvroot directory but the results were the same.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you are trying to connect to a secured store without specifying the secured connection parameters. Oracle NoSQL has enabled security by default. The simplest thing you can try is to start kvlite with security disabled.

```
java -Xmx256m -Xms256m -jar KVHOME/lib/kvstore.jar kvlite -secure-config disable
```

also, I noticed you were looking at docs for older version. The latest NoSQL is now 4.4.6 and the docs are breathing here - http://docs.oracle.com/cd/NOSQL/html/GettingStartedGuide/kvlite-usage.html

HTH,

Comment: Thank you, however, I'm still having issues.  I started kvlite as suggested above, but the resulting output still shows security enabled and I am still having the same problem.  `Opened existing kvlite store with config:  -root ./kvroot -store kvstore -host MYHOST -port 5000 -secure-config enable`

Comment: Additional Information: I removed the "security" line from config.xml and tried the above command again.  kvlite started with -secure-config disabled but when I compiled and ran the HelloWorld example, I still get an exception that says "Could not contact any RepNode".

Comment: @DropOfGoldenSun the problem is indeed with your security settings. I was able to reproduce this easily. to resolve this - I simply cleaned up my env i.e. kvroot directory. restarted kvlite with security-disable and I was able to get this going. these are the steps I followed `\rm -rf kvroot` 
`java -jar ./lib/kvstore.jar kvlite -secure-config disable`
`java -jar ./lib/kvstore.jar ping`
`java -cp lib/kvclient.jar:examples hello.HelloBigDataWorld -host localhost -port 5000`

Comment: To run the same example with security enabled you will need to add following flag -Doracle.kv.security=<KVROOT>/security/user.security as mentioned in the latest kvlite verify install documentation - http://docs.oracle.com/cd/NOSQL/html/GettingStartedGuide/verifykvlite.html