# JMX JBoss non-JRMP server at remote endpoint

Tags: jboss, jmx, jboss6.x, jconsole, jrmp

JConsole is failing remote connection to JBoss JMX. As understood JMX is enabled by default in JBoss 6.4, using the management-native port, as per below config

standalone-full.xml

```
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jmx:1.3">
        <expose-resolved-model/>
        <expose-expression-model/>
        <remoting-connector use-management-endpoint="true"/>
    </subsystem>
 <socket-binding name="management-native" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.native.port:9999}"/>
```

Using JConsole from Windows machine, trying to make Remote Connection to remote host 192.168.1.1:9999, with JBoss CLI (also listening on port 9999) username and password credentials.

Getting error

> Connection Failed: non-JRMP server at remote endpoint

I'm running TCPDump on remote host and can see the incoming request from Jconsole

I have tried [non-JRMP server at remote endpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43665179/non-jrmp-server-at-remote-endpoint) , and others to no avail

Any help will be appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Did you try using a different port for jmx from your application (eg:  8080 for app, 8084 for jmx)?